# How add one object with a similar Parent and another object with a similar GrandParent to the same Object List

Tags: java, c#, oop, object

For example, I have an abstract class ShapeParent that has an abstract method CalculateArea();

```
public abstract class ShapeParent
{
    public abstract void CalculateArea();
}
```

I then have two child objects which extend ShapeParent and implement CalculateArea(); The first one is Rectangle:

```
public class Rectangle : ShapeParent
{
    public override void CalculateArea()
    {
        //Area calculated here
    }
}
```

And the second one is circle:

```
public class Circle : ShapeParent
{
    public override void CalculateArea()
    {
        //Area calculated here
    }
}
```

And consider the scenario where I have also have a generic Shape class that also extends ShapeParent. This shape class will be a generic container for all the other shapes to be used in Collections/Lists. It has an additional method called GetType() which gets the underlying Shape type:

```
public class Shape : ShapeParent
    {
        public object UnderLyingShape { get; set; }
        public override void CalculateArea()
        {
            ((ShapeParent)UnderLyingShape).CalculateArea();
        }

        public Type GetType()
        {
            return ((ShapeParent)UnderLyingShape).GetType();
        }
    }
```

I will then declare a List of the following:

```
    private readonly List<Shapes> _myShapes = new List<Shapes>();
```

This all works fine, but consider when I want to add a new Shape type which is a volumable shape, such as a Cylinder, with a new method CalculateVolume(); to this List of Shapes.

What is the best way to do this? Can I make CylinderParent object that extends ShapeParent so it picks up the CalculateArea() method and adds an abstract definition for CalculateVolume() which a Cylinder object would then implement? But can I add this to the list of Shapes since the common object is a GrandParent for this object but a Parent for the rest? Is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider making the "Volumable Shape" an interface. i.e. `IVolumable`. You could do that for the Area Calculation too ( e.g. `IAreaCalculable`). This way you can check if a shapeparent implements a particular behaviour and call it if possible, if not perhaps ignore it, or just store shapes as the behaviour you want in the List.

To be honest Shape could probably be an interface as well, because thats all it seems to be acting as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Note: if understand your code well than shape is a subclass of shape parent therefore it is sibling to the actual implementations. Is this your goal?

As projects grows inheritance trees can become very large and complicated. Instead traversing branches and leaves on a hierarchy tree maybe you can try grab behaviours with interfaces.

Eg. One interface for the calculateArea and one for the volume. Your shapes can implement multiple interfaces according to their behaviour and you can collect them in a list of basic interface.